# convert dynamic GMT date to timestamp with timezone in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, timestamp-with-timezone

There is an requirement where, my oracle procedure is called by a java api using REST or SOAP call.

sample procedure

```
 procedure sample(id in varchar2(30),logged_dt in varchar2(30),name out varchar2(30))
BEGIN
<DATE CONVERSION LOGIC>
END;
/
```

the logged_dt input is passed as a GMT date format in any of below cases like,

1. 2016-10-06T06:29:55-04:00
2. 2016-10-08T14:01:27Z

i need to handle whatever the dateformat comes and convert into required oracle UTC timezone format.

i converted one sample case

'2016-10-06T11:31:28.592+0000’

```
to_timestamp_tz(to_timestamp('2016-10-06T11:31:28.592+0000’,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"+0000"') at time zone 'UTC')
```

how to dynamically cast whatever comes over the INPUT procedure to the required format and convert it to the timezone UTC format

Answer (score 1):

It will be de difficult to handle "input in whatever comes", have a look at various world-wide date formats: [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) or [Date Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Date_format)

However, in order to handle the input values you provided as example you can use a function like this one:

```
FUNCTION String2Timestamp(ts IN VARCHAR2) RETURN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(ts, '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\+|-)\d{2}:\d{2}$') THEN
        RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZM:TZH') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    ELSIF REGEXP_LIKE(ts, '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z$') THEN
        RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    END IF;
END String2Timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, really it help me a lot.just amazing.